# Allow users to comment on questions they already have comments on

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges, comments-as-answers

I suggest that users be able to comment on questions where they already have comments. This is obviously an edge case, since it requires that either a user posts a comment and then drops below the rep threshold, or that a moderator converts an answer to a comment. It is the second case I mainly want to address. Usually, or at least theoretically, when a moderator turns an answer into a comment it means that it was useful enough to keep around as a comment. Once a user has demonstrated that they can make useful comments on a question, it seems reasonable to allow them to make more comments on that question. This would be mainly useful for clarification questions, which can require some multi-step communication between the asker and the commenter.

This idea comes from [this question of mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103549/what-do-i-do-in-the-glass-box-in-the-chase), where a user seems to be trying to post useful clarification questions, but the rep threshold means that either he can't get the clarification he may need to answer the question or moderators will keep turning his answers into comments (unlikely, since his current behavior is basically abusive).

It should be easy to prevent abuse of this, since there would be very few questions where this could happen at all, and it could be stopped just by clearing that user's comments on the question where abuse is happening.

Comment: Wow. I just started to write a question with the title "Allow a user to comment on any post they already have a comment on", thinking it was a silly title

Comment: The fact that the user is violating the site rules and posting comments as answers makes me all the less likely to want to trust them to post comments early.  Clearly they are unfamiliar with how the site is supposed to function.  One main reason the limit is there is to give users time to learn how to properly use the system.  Clearly a user having an answer converted to a comment needs to spend *more* time learning.

Comment: murg & Michael M. Seemed like a good idea, but I down voted (rare for me!). I think @Servy is correct AND because - as you said so yourself - it's "obviously an edge case."  The infrastructure change involved is probably fairly minor, but the idea doesn't seem to justify such change (IMO). Consider this other angle: if either scenario you describe happens, and the user wants to do more, but can not, they get rather mild negative reinforcement - so it can be a teaching moment. The user has to learn more ropes, (hopefully) making them a better user, improving the site. Unsure your idea does so.

Comment: @Servy If the answer was good enough to be converted to a comment, then clearly they're capable of writing useful comments. If they can't, they're just going to post another answer since it worked out so well for them last time

Comment: @Servy: The site rules need to cover every case, which is why commenting needs 50 reputation in the first place. SE does not disallow *every* new user to comment for its own sake; it only does so, because it cannot read minds and weed out the spammers, trolls etc. beforehand. If you want to enforce this rule for its own sake, you should advocate that nobody may convert answers of users with less than 50 reputation to comments.